# Laravel API overriding default 413 Payload Too Large response

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating file uploader in my Laravel API, but seems like when I upload a file that is too large, the response is muddled up and I can't really figure out how to solve. Here is a screenshot of my postman request:
[image]

As you can see if have `application/json` header, and what is bugging me is the PHP error before the empty json response. What I want instead is for the warning message not to appear and the response to be customised.

I tried adding the exception to my `Handler.php` as follows, but made not much difference (although I am not 100% sure this is the correct exception to intercept as its not being logged):

```
public function register() {
    $this->renderable(function (Throwable $e, Request $request) {
        //
        switch($e) {
            case $e instanceof \PostTooLargeException:
                response()->json(['message' => "The size of the selected file is too large.", "success" => false], 413);
                break;
            default:
                response()->json(['message' => 'Server error.', 'success' => false], 500);

        }

    });
}
```

Controller function I am posting to:

```
public function uploadTo(Request $request, $album_id) {
    if(!$request->hasFile('image')) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'File not found', 'success' => false], 400);
    }

    $file = $request->file('image');
    if(!$file->isValid()) {
        return response()->json(['message' => "Invalid file upload.", "success" => false], 400);
    }

    $album = Album::where('id', $album_id)->first();
    //\Storage::disk('frontend')->allFiles($this->folder_name);

    $file->store("$album->folder_name", ["disk"=>"frontend"]);
    //$file->move($path, $file->getClientOriginalName());

    return response()->json(['message'=>"Upload successful.", "success" => true], 200);
}
```

What am i doing wrong here? Just to be clear I **do not** want to increase the upload size / php size limit, I just want to intercept the error message and return a graceful error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your php.ini (you can put any size you like)

```
max_file_uploads=100
post_max_size=120M
upload_max_filesize=120M
```

If you are using homestead try also to update nginx (

> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
http {
      client_max_body_size 50M;         
}
```

restart after that

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: Thanks but like I said in the opening post I am aware that I can just update the limit, but I don't want to. I consider it unsafe to just increase the limit to the sky, and its not a solution to an issue.. just pushes the limit out. The issue is that there should be a way to return a proper error instead of the warning and empty response. Ps. there will actually be a chunked uploader here so in theory this error should never appear anyway but "shouldnt happen" isn't protection ;)

Comment: Well, increasing the limit doesn't you are insecure, you just need to set a min of the uploaded file.. if you gonna work with multiple file uploads I'm sure you will need to do this step especially for nginx.
I think the errors it caught from nginx http before your code validation

Comment: Yeah that makes sense since the warning is from line 0, but is there no other way to solving this than to increasing the limit? My issue is is that I can raise the limit to say 100MB... but then someone selects something that is 101MB, the same error is still going to happen that the frontend cant even parse properly because its invalid json. Do you see the issue? I understand that nginx is intercepting it early but the only way this would solve the actual issue is to set the limit to some unholy number that im not going to do.

Comment: You can validate the size in the front end and if it passes the front end somehow you will validate it in the backend .. 
So the file will not harm you since is not uploaded yet to your server

Comment: Surely if the frontend validation doesnt catch it by size (lets say both nginx limit and frontend limit is set to the same), then the server will still return the same error as above rather than my own validation error message? Since the file would still be exceeding the max post size... so again, I would have to set it to a very high limit so that nothing that they can select in theory would ever exceed the limit (so that i can do my own validation everywhere). This is my problem, i dont want to have to set to 99999999999gb so that I know I can **always** rely on my own validation

Comment: Yes, personally I set it to 0, then I take control.. because if one day I decided to increase the size I'll just update the JS/ backend .. if I update the Nginx as well I need to restart it and this behavior is not recommended if you were using CRON jobs that may fail without any exception

Comment: well isnt setting to 0 going to make this warning appear for ANY request? ;P i still dont understand how to actually overcome the annoying error before the json response...

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

After all I had to mess around with my `php.ini` settings, but only setting `display_startup_errors = Off` gets rid of the annoying warning, then changing `\PostTooLargeException` in my `Handler.php` to `\Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\PostTooLargeException` properly catches the exception and overrides the error.